# How to Print elements of the Sorted Array up to the Middle Element and then Back to zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop

I need to create a For Loop in Javascript to print the elements of the "Sorted Array" up to the "Middle element" value.

Once the loop reaches the cycle of the middle element, print the elements in descending order, from current value back to index 0.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
var r6 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100];

r6.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});; // I have a sorted array
r6.length; // I have the length of the array
var theMiddle = Math.floor(r6.length / 2); // I know the Middle element;
var value = r6[theMiddle];


// I need to create a For Loop to print the elements of the "Sorted Array" up to the "Middle element" value.
for (a = 0; a < r6.length / 2; a++) {

  document.writeln(r6[a]);
}

document.writeln("<br/>");
//Once the loop reaches the cycle of the middle element, print the elements in descending order, from current value back to index 0.


for (var i = r6.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  document.writeln(r6[i]);
}
```

Preferably I would like to make all of the prints to be In-line.
How can I make the descending order For loop to start from 50 and down to 0 print? ( As you can see that I made it work from 100 to 0)
How can I make it in-line to be printed? (by using a Nested loop?)

Comment: If you want it to be on a line, why are you printing `<br/>`? ...

Comment: By making it iterate from the middle of the array instead of the end, of course. If you understand what your code is doing that should be easy.

Comment: Also... why do you calculate `middleElement` and `value` and never use them?

Comment: No offense Alex but it sounds like you're asking the stackoverflow community to do your homework for you.

Comment: @user202729 I\m using <br/> just for here to show that separately. But the whole point is to make it work from the middle. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Rocky Sims hmm. As a new to Javascript, I'm asking StackOverflow comunnity to help me out may be a more often then I have to, but Only when I'm struggling with some type of code. I know you might wanna say that before asking to Do some research which I did and there are tons of examples but now exactly like I got. I'm just trying to get a point from more experienced folks no more than that. And from what I see is that a lot of folks start judging you like (why he's asking so silly question or sort of like that). But that Ok, cause we all know that that is what human being like to be. right?

Comment: That's fair. Now that I understand where you're at, I see how to answer your question without simply telling you the answer (which doesn't help much with being able to apply it to new situations).

Comment: Within the past 3 days, I've seen this question asked 3 different times on SO.  Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

This is really quite straight forward. You just need to understand how for loops work and the answer becomes obvious so let me go over the anatomy of some for loops for you in the context of iterating over an array.

First we'll define the array I'll use in my examples below.

```
var ary = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
//indexes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
//length: 10
```

---

Let's start with a for loop that iterates through an array from first element to last.

```
var startIndex = 0;
//0 is the index of the first element
var endIndex = ary.length - 1;
// 10 - 1 = 9 which is the index of the last element

for (var curIndex = startIndex; curIndex <= endIndex; curIndex++) {
    console.log(ary[curIndex]);
}
//this will log:
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
```

Essentially there are 3 parts to the for loop:

1. `var curIndex = startIndex`
   This is where you tell it which index you want it to start on.
2. `curIndex <= endIndex`
   This is where you tell it which index you want it to end on.
3. `curIndex++`
   This is where you tell it which direction to go (and how far to go per iteration).

---

So now what if we want to iterate from the first element to the middle?
All we have to do is change `var endIndex = ary.length - 1;` to `var endIndex = Math.floor(ary.length / 2) - 1;`. Essentially we're doing the same calculation except we're pretending the array is half as long so that we get the index of the **middle** element instead of the index of the last element.

```
var startIndex = 0;
//0 is the index of the first element
var endIndex = Math.floor(ary.length / 2) - 1;
// (10 / 2) - 1 = 4 which is the index of the middle element

for (var curIndex = startIndex; curIndex <= endIndex; curIndex++) {
    console.log(ary[curIndex]);
}
//this will log:
0
10
20
30
40
```

---

Now let's look at a for loop that iterates from the last element to the first. This is basically the same as my first example except `curIndex++` changes to `curIndex--` since we want to count down not up and because we're counting down `curIndex <= endIndex` needs to change to `curIndex >= endIndex` (since we want to stop iterating once `curIndex` goes below `endIndex` instead of when it goes above it).

```
var startIndex = ary.length - 1;
var endIndex = 0;

for (var curIndex = startIndex; curIndex >= endIndex; curIndex--) {
    console.log(ary[curIndex]);
}
//this will log:
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
0
```

---

So now what if we want to iterate from the middle element to the first? What do we need to set `startIndex` to (in the example above) if we want it to start at the middle element?

---

In answer to the other part of your question, your results are being printed on two different lines because you told it to add a line break by saying `document.writeln("<br/>");`.